# Child element's width is changed but the parent element's width doesn't change, why?

Tags: html, css, web

[reference](http://gridster.net/demos/dynamic-grid-width.html)

In this page,  when `.gridster > ul`'s width is changed, but `.gridster`'s width stays. Normally, parent element's width changes as the child element's width changes. Why it stays the same in this case. How to make the parent element's width is equal to the child element's all the time.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to ask... The .gridster doesn't have a set width and is display at 100% width. The child ul has a grey background and is expanding within it's parent div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `.gridster` is a block-level non-replaced element.

> [**10.3 Calculating widths and margins**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins)
>   [**10.3.3 Block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth)
>
> The following constraints must hold among the used values of the other
>   properties:
>
> ```
> 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of  containing block
> ```
>
> If ['width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width) is set to 'auto', any other 'auto' values become '0' and
>   ['width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width) follows from the resulting equality.

In this case,

- The `width` is not set, so its value is the initial `auto`.
- The horizontal margins are set to `auto`.
- The horizontal `border-*-style` are not set, so their value is the initial `none`. Thus the horizontal `border-*-width` compute to `0`.
- The horizontal paddings are not set, so their value is the initial `0`.

Then,

- The horizontal borders and paddings remain `0`.
- The horizontal margins compute to `0` because the `width` is `auto`.
- The `width` computes to the width of the [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details).